# Why are members trying to downvote questions or find flaws in the questions?

Tags: discussion

Rather than making an effort to answer questions members are more obsessed with correcting the structure of questions. Questions don't necessarily carry a question mark. I post a problem for which I need solution but for people here they need to have it in their format.

Comment: FYI How do I ask a good question? (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Often there is not enough information in post, and we are not soothsayers

Answer (score 8):

This is a **Q+A site**. We are building a **repository of knowledge about Drupal**, and we want that knowledge to be displayed in a **high quality, useful format**.

What this means is that questions need to be well thought out, descriptive, comprehensive, and structured in a way that will be useful to future visitors who have the same problem.

To help with this, we have a community of volunteers, the same community of volunteers who are giving up their free time to answer your questions, incidentally, who have earned the right to curate content that falls short of those standards.

This includes editing to improve grammar/clarity, voting up and down if questions are good or bad, useful to this site, etc., voting to close if a question is unclear or simply doesn't belong here, commenting to get clarification, and so on. These are probably the phenomena you're talking about.

To cut through the fluff, this is where the disconnect in understanding has happened:

> I post a problem for which I need solution

With the best will in the world, and total respect and smiles to your good self, we don't care about that. The fact that you get a solution to a problem is a wonderful side-effect, but we, very and necessarily selfishly, are only interested in getting good content onto this site. If we see a question that has potential, but isn't good enough yet, we'll either edit it into shape, or ask *you*, the person who's asking for free expert help, don't forget, to do what you should have done before posting the question in the first place.

That's the trade-off. You can get excellent help here, from people who really know Drupal well, but you've got to put the effort in yourself to give us a good question for the repository.

If you think these are unreasonable requirements to get free expert help, I think Stack Exchange is not going to be the best place for you to seek assistance. We don't want this to turn into another Yahoo Answers, we all know how crap that got, so our standards are not going to be compromised.

Personally I hope you take this advice, now realising that you've perhaps misunderstood what the site is for, and how you're supposed to use it, and will endeavour to ask high quality questions in the future.

Note: I haven't actually looked at any of your questions so I'm not commenting either way on their quality, this is all general advice.

Comment: I commented (not downvoted) on his earlier question saying that data he provided is not enough to answer, and that he didn't even really ask a question, just reported his issue. So your general answer fits perfectly his specific question I've seen.

Comment: No this was not based on the previous question. I had another account where most of my questions were downvoted - I tried in every possible manner to impress members with my questioning way from the best of my knowledge but still couldn't get adequate help. But one thing I understood clearly - Be controversial, get promoted as editor, get the meta privilege etc [1/2]

Comment: To Mr. Clive -- I'll definitely take that advice thanks for answering I'll be more sensible, precise and meet the demands while I post a question the next time. I got enough clarity I required. And if by any means I wasted your time Im so sorry for that that wasnt at all my intention. [2/2]